# JBOSS EAP 7 unable to connect to database on sql 2016 server

Tags: sql-server-2016, hibernate-4.x, mssql-jdbc, jboss-eap-7

I am working on a upgrade project where in the SQL servers are being updated to msssql 2016. I am using mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar and java 8u121. With the same driver application is able to establish connection with database on sql 2012 server. But fails with the error saying that unable to establish connection to database.

Stacktrace below.

```
18:33:12,325 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:160 - begin
18:33:12,325 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:226 - Obtaining JDBC connection
18:33:12,325 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:294 - Property:serverName Value:SQL-2016-server
18:33:12,325 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:320 - Property:portNumber Value:1433
18:33:12,325 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:396 - Property:databaseName Value:Test_Database
18:33:12,325 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:399 - Property:password
18:33:12,325 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:507 - Property:instanceName Value:Architecture
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:920 - ConnectionID:2 created by (SQLServerDriver:1)
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:1910 - ConnectionID:2 This attempt server name: SQL-2016-server port: 1433 InstanceName: Architecture useParallel: false
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:1913 - ConnectionID:2 This attempt endtime: 1541682194201
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:1914 - ConnectionID:2 This attempt No: 0
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:2228 - ConnectionID:2 Connecting with server: SQL-2016-server port: 1433 Timeout slice: 1875 Timeout Full: 15
18:33:12,326 DEBUG AbstractTransactionImpl:160 - begin
18:33:12,326 DEBUG LogicalConnectionImpl:226 - Obtaining JDBC connection
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:2547 - ConnectionID:2 ClientConnectionId: 887cb0e6-c7f7-4467-b1e3-ce1ccaeb5057 Server returned major version:13
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:294 - Property:serverName Value:SQL-2016-server
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:320 - Property:portNumber Value:1433
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:396 - Property:databaseName Value: Test_Database
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:399 - Property:password
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerDriver:507 - Property:instanceName Value:Architecture
18:33:12,326 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:920 - ConnectionID:3 created by (SQLServerDriver:1)
18:33:12,358 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:1910 - ConnectionID:3 This attempt server name: SQL-2016-server port: 1433 InstanceName: Architecture useParallel: false
18:33:12,358 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:1913 - ConnectionID:3 This attempt endtime: 1541682194233
18:33:12,358 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:1914 - ConnectionID:3 This attempt No: 0
18:33:12,358 DEBUG SQLServerConnection:2228 - ConnectionID:3 Connecting with server: Test_Database port: 1433 Timeout slice: 1875 Timeout Full: 15
18:33:12,358 DEBUG SQLServerException:102 - *** SQLException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'dbuser'. ClientConnectionId:xxx Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Login failed for user 'dbuser'. ClientConnectionId:887cb0e6-c7f7-4467-b1e3-ce1ccaeb5057
18:33:12,358 DEBUG SqlExceptionHelper:139 - Could not open connection [n/a]
```

Official jboss documentation does not confirm weather SQL 2016 works with JBOSS EAP - 7, it just mentions it is un-tested.

I am able to login to said database using the same user account from Management Studio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a managed connection or a connection you're manually creating? How was the JDBC driver installed?

Comment: How exactly are you using this driver as a module or deployment?Are you able to access the db directly via standalone java application on the system.without using EAP,is it accessible?